# What is the reason for not recognizing the TensorFlow after installation?

Tags: python, tensorflow, conda

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0j2K.png)

All 4 installation steps were performed , on **32 bit windows**:

> 1.conda create -n tensorN python=3.6
>
> 2.activate tensorN
>
> 3.conda install -c hesi_m tensorflow
>
> 4.pip install tensorflow

but when trying

```
import tensorflow
```

it shows the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named "tensorflow"
```

Comment: why pip install AND conda install? Did the commands report any error or report success?

Comment: It was written in the installation tutorial.write success after install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do `conda activate tensorN` before running `import tensorflow`. You have installed tensorflow in env `tensorN` and you will be able to access it only in the environment

Comment: thanks for help, I did it , but It sent a long error.

Comment: activating env or import statement. What sent the long error?

Comment: its very long has 6000 ch .      (tensorN) λ python tensorN_1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensorN\lib\site-pack
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_i

Comment: Which statement is throwing the error? `conda activate tensorflow` or `import tensorflow`

Comment: import tensorflow

Comment: now ,again send (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named "tensorflow")

Comment: u need to remain in the environment. I think it would be best if you read up on hon pytenvironments a little

Comment: I did not understand what you mean